# longest distance from point to rounded rectangle or ellipse

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

How can I find the longest distance from a point inside a shape to its border.

I am in particular trying to find the distance for these cases:

Example 3 (right without rounded corners) would be the lower right corner but how can I calculate the other 2?

[image]

I am looking for a JavaScript solution but I'm happy with basic logical explanations too.

Here's the script I am using to get the farthest corner:

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/pJXxPZ/)

```
// the bounding box
var bound = document.getElementById('bound')
var radius = parseInt(getComputedStyle(bound).borderRadius, 10);
// listen to events
bound.addEventListener('mousedown', getFarthest)

/**
 * get the fartest point from click to border
 **/
function getFarthest(event) {
  // get event coordinates
  var y = event.layerY;
  var x = event.layerX;
  // get event dimensions
  var w = event.target.offsetWidth;
  var h = event.target.offsetHeight;

  // get offset
  var offsetX = Math.abs(w / 2 - x);
  var offsetY = Math.abs(h / 2 - y);

  // get delta
  var deltaX = w / 2 + offsetX;
  var deltaY = h / 2 + offsetY;

  // calculate size
  var size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2) - 2 * deltaX * deltaY * Math.cos(90 / 180 * Math.PI));

  event.target.innerText = Math.round(size);
}
```

Comment: @ne1410s See the 2nd line. it gets the radius from the element. Also check the example from codepen I posted.

Comment: You can simplify your size calculation to just use the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) instead of the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) since `cos(90/180*PI)` is zero.

Comment: @GreenGiant  thx for the tip..

Comment: the middle figure does never occur, right? I believe `border-radius` defaults to the smallest of `width/2` and `height/2` if it is bigger than one or both of those.

Comment: @Sumurai8 correct. my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In html, radius creates 4 circles in the corners. I am pretty sure that no matter where you click, the furthest point is always in one of the corners, because the line to the furthest point has a 90 degree corner with the edge. The furthest point is also always in the opposite quadrant. Please note that in html, the radius cannot be larger than `width/2` and `height/2`. It is thus impossible to make an actual ellipse.

Because the line will always have a 90 degree corner with the edge, we know that the line should go through the middle of the circle. Every other line would not be able to make a 90 degree corner with the edge of the circle. To calculate the distance we only need to do Pythagoras between the point we clicked, and the middle of the circle. The distance between the middle of the circle and the edge of the circle was already known, because that is the radius.

## The code

```js
// listen to events
bound.addEventListener('mousedown', getFarthest)

/**
 * get the fartest point from click to border
 **/
function getFarthest(event) {
  //In IE the computed border radius is an empty string, causing parseInt to make it NaN.
  var radius = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(event.target).borderRadius, 10);

  if( radius === NaN ) {
    event.target.innerText = "ERROR";
    console.error( "Computed radius is not a number in this browser." );
    return;
  }
  
  // get event coordinates
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  
  //get the width and height of the element
  var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  //We know that the furthest point is in the opposite quarter, on the rounded bit
  //The greatest distance is the point where the line to the edge has a 90 degrees corner
  //with the edge. This only happens if the line goes through the center of the circle
  //the distance between the center of a circle and it's edge is... the radius.
  //the distance between the center of a circle and a point is simple pythagoras.
  //Thus, we don't need to know where it intersects to find the distance.
  var circleX;
  var circleY;
  
  //Find the middle point of the circle
  if( x < (rect.width / 2) ) {
    circleX = rect.width - radius;
  } else {
    circleX = radius;
  }
  if( y < (rect.height / 2) ) {
    circleY = rect.height - radius;
  } else {
    circleY = radius;
  }
  
  var pythagoras = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( circleX - x, 2 ) + Math.pow( circleY - y, 2 ) );
  
  var distance = pythagoras + radius;

  //Put it in a suitable place
  event.target.innerText = Math.round( distance );
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #424242;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wire {
  display: block;

  width: 10em;
  height: 20em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20em;
  margin: -10em -5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0em;
  background: white;
}

.tracker {
  background: red;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<span id="bound" class="wire">Area</span>
```

## Somewhat of a proof

[image: Corners are always further away]
This image shows that corners are always further away than the sides of the shape. `r` is the radius. `a`, `b` and `c` are the terms used in pythagoras. `c` will always be larger than `a` or `b`, thus `c + r` will always be larger than `a + r` or `b + r`.

[image: Tangent and secants]
This image shows why the secant will always be shorter. Line A is the longest line. Line B is a secant. The blue striped circle has middle point where line A and B begin, and goes through the point where line B intersects our circle. All points on the blue striped circle have the same distance to where line A and B begin. As you can clearly see, line A is longer, because it goes through the blue circle. If one were to create a circle with middle point where A and B begin, and a radius of where A intersects the circle, it would not intersect with our shape anywhere except where A intersects the circle.

Comment: There is some logic error. clicking in each of the 4 corners should always return the same value. but it differs from bottom to top in your example. The corner is always the furthest until the corner gets a radius. then the point moves on that circle. The line does not always intersect with the center of the circle that creates the radius, otherwise it would extend the diameter. It is rather a `secant` to the circle.

Comment: I have fixed an error where I used `rect.bottom` instead of `rect.height`. The bottom corners should now give the same numbers +/- 1 pixel as the top corners. As for the other point: See brainjam's answer. If the line from our point to the edge is not perpendicular (or a 90 degree corner with the tangent), there is a longer line that is perpendicular to the tangent. The only places where this happens is the straight edge above, below, to the left and to the right of our point, and in each of the corners. Pythagoras tells me that the line to the corner is always longer than the straight edge.

Comment: I have added somewhat of a visual proof that the corner circles are always the furthest point, and that a secant will always be shorter than the line that goes through the middle, and thus is perpendicular to the tangent. I think it should speak for itself that a line that goes through the middle point of the opposite corner always ends up on the circle, because the middle point can not be anywhere past `height/2` and `width/2`.

Answer (score 4):

Basic logical explanation:

You're looking for points X on the shape where the tangent at X is perpendicular to the red point P.

The rectangle is a special case, because the corners don't have well defined tangents.  But you've handled that case already.

As for the ellipse and rounded corners, I assume you know how to calculate tangents (if not, Google it). Find the expression for the tangent at a given point X=(x,y), as well an expression for the line from P to X.  When these are perpendicular (dot product of their directions is zero), you have a candidate.  Calculate all of these candidate points, then find out which one is farthest from P.